# platform difference?

Tags: c++

I was trying out the bitset class in C++ and I tried this with the number 137 as an example:
So, I converted it to binary number which gave me 10001001. Now, I wanted to cut off the MSB and store the rest bits 0001001 in another bit instance called bitarray and I was expecting to see that in the bitarray but it wasn't giving the right value. what could have been the problem? I was just trying to split the MSB from the rest of the bits in the 137 binary representation...here is the code:

```
bitset<8> bitarray;

bitset<8> bitsetObject(num);
int val = bitsetObject.size();

for (int i = 0; i <= (val - 1); i++)
{
    if (i == 6)
        break;
    else
        bitarray[i] = bitsetObject[i + 1];
}
```

If anyone knows how I could easily slice from the second element to the last element in the bitsetObject array, let me know. Thanks..

Comment: "but it wasn't giving the right value." - I call this "not enough information".

Comment: Exactly what value was being returned?

Comment: `if (i == 6)` should really be `if (i == 7)`...

Answer (score 2):

If you're just trying to make a new `bitset` object with the most significant set bit reset, then consider the following:

```
template<std::size_t N>
std::bitset<N> strip_mssb(std::bitset<N> bitarray)
{
    for (std::size_t i = bitarray.size(); i--;)
        if (bitarray[i])
        {
            bitarray.reset(i);
            break;
        }
    return bitarray;
}
```

[Online demo.](http://ideone.com/8ul49)

Comment: I am not trying to reset it. I just want to slice off the MSB and store the rest bits in another array.

Comment: @henry : That is _exactly_ what this code does. Have you read it? Have you tried it?

Comment: That is why i am asking here. I only need a way to slice off the MSB and store the rest bits in another array. so, how do i slice off the MSB and store the rest?

Comment: Shouldn't it be simply `bitarray.reset(7)` without any loop at all? I take MSB as being the highest bit for the data type, not the highest bit that is set to 1.

Comment: @Remy : Referring to this wording in the OP: "*Now, I wanted to cut off the MSB and store the rest bits 0001001 in another bit instance*", I interpreted it as wanting to reset the most significant _set_ bit. But agreed -- by your interpretation it should be simply `bitarray.reset(N-1);`. :-] I'm not positive which the OP is really after.

Answer (score 1):

You set `bitarray[0]` equal to `bitsetObject[1]`, which is 0 (assuming `num` is really 137).

You seem to expect the least bit of `bitarray` to be equal to 1.